# Java project packaged as a jar containing another drools project as a dependency not starting

Tags: maven, spring-boot, drools

I have a maven Spring-boot project named 'controller', which has another project 'webservices' as a dependency. 'webservices' is a Drools project (kmodule.xml is located in src/main/resources/META-INF/ folder inside webservices project).

Now when I start controller project from Eclipse, it works fine. However, when I pack it as a jar, and try to start it using `java -jar controller.jar`, it says `Found kmodule: jar:file:controller-0.1.jar!/lib/webservices-0.1.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml` and gets stuck after that. It doesn't throw any errors. But it doesn't start either.

What is wrong here? It is able to find the kmodule file, so that is not the problem. Why is it not starting?

===============  Update  =================

It is starting, but it takes almost half hour to bring it up. Earlier I had webservices as a separate project and it used to start in about 3 mins. However it used to stop at the same step for about 2 mins. Now, after half hour, I get this log:

```
o.d.c.k.b.i.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added:ZipKieModule[ ReleaseId=controller:0.1file=Desktop/controller-0.1.jar]
```

And after this is starts immediately.

============== Update 2 =================

I tried moving the kmodule.xml and the rules file to the "controller" project, build the KSession object in controller, and then pass it to the webservices project. It is still taking half hour.

This is my project structure:

```
controller
  |__ src/main/java
  |__ src/main/resources
         |__ rules
               |__ mypkg1
                     |__ rules1.drl
               |__ mypkg2
                     |__ rules2.drl
         |__ META-INF
               |__ kmodule.xml
```

My kmodule.xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="Kbase1" packages="rules.mypkg1.rules">
        <ksession name="abc" type="stateless"/>
    </kbase>
    <kbase name="Kbase2" packages="rules.mypkg2.rules">
        <ksession name="xyz" type="stateless"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

From controller, I call a class in webservices, which uses drools. This is how I'm calling the class in webservices project which uses drools:

```
public class ControllerClass {
    StatelessKieSession kSession;
    KieServices kieService;
    KieContainer kContainer;

    public ReturnsController() {
        kieService = KieServices.Factory.get();
        kContainer = kieService.getKieClasspathContainer();
    }

    public void callWebservices(String kSessionName){
        kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession(kSessionName);
        WebservicesClass wc = new WebservicesClass();
        wc.callDroolsMethod(kSession);
    }
}
```

The rules files are short, each containing about 10 rules max. Starting the drools engine directly from webservices project takes only about 3 mins. The controller project on its own is very light, so I doubt it's because of memory issue.

Thanks.

Comment: depending on how big your drools file is, it sounds like you are trying to load the entire thing into memory and you have not allocated enough memory for the file (plus your app) - we had a similar issue with a web app and the solutions was to break down the drools file into smaller 'groups' of rules/conditions and only load the needed ones at run time.  Loading/unloading new files took a couple of seconds each time but the overall performance of the web app was improved tons... hard to know if this is your case or not tho'

Comment: @ochi Thx. But it doesn't look like that is the problem. I tried setting the heap size manually, and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: there is not much to go on here.  How big is your drools file? let's start with that! how much memory does it consume? how much memory do you have?

Comment: @ochi I have updated my question with sample code. I'm wondering if the way I load the rules file is inefficient.

Comment: If your rules files are that small, I concur I doubt the issue is in the loading of the rules.  I am not what could be causing such a delay... Are the rules very complex?

Comment: No, they are very simple rules. Just checking for some values and setting other values based on that.

Comment: let me check some old code here to see what I can recall (it's been a while)